# (MoveNext() not all code paths return a value) c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Error: (MoveNext() not all code paths return a value)

WHAT TO DO???
This is a really strange mistake ... I don’t know what it is

There is also a problem with goto, not sure how it works

```
public override bool MoveNext()
            {
                switch (this._state)
                {
                    case 0:
                    IL_1F:
                        if (!this._self__55.movingPlatform.enabled || (this._self__55.movingPlatform.movementTransfer != MovementTransferOnJump.InitTransfer && this._self__55.movingPlatform.movementTransfer != MovementTransferOnJump.PermaTransfer))
                        {
                            goto IL_124;
                        }
                        if (this._self__55.movingPlatform.newPlatform)
                        {
                            this._platform_54 = this._self__55.movingPlatform.activePlatform;
                            int arg_12D_0 = this.Yield(2, new WaitForFixedUpdate()) ? 1 : 0;
                            return arg_12D_0 != 0;
                        }
                        goto IL_EF;
                case 1:
                        {

                        IL_12C:
                            int arg_12D_0 = 0;
                            return arg_12D_0 != 0;
                        }
                case 2:
                {
                    int arg_12D_0 = this.Yield(3, new WaitForFixedUpdate()) ? 1 : 0;
                    return arg_12D_0 != 0;
                }
                case 3:
                    if (this._self__55.grounded && this._platform_54 == this._self__55.movingPlatform.activePlatform)
                    {
                        int arg_12D_0 = this.Yield(4, 1) ? 1 : 0;
                        return arg_12D_0 != 0;
                    }
                    goto IL_EF;
                case 4:
                    goto IL_EF;
                    goto IL_1F;
                }
                IL_EF:
                this._self__55.movement.velocity = this._self__55.movement.velocity - this._self__55.movingPlatform.platformVelocity;
                IL_124:
                this.YieldDefault(1);
            }
```

Comment: Oh wow, I haven't seen spaghetti code like this for a very long time! My advice is NEVER use a `goto`.

Comment: Yes, I know, tell me better how to fix the error.

Comment: This looks like something that came out of a decompiler.

Comment: rule of thumb: `goto` is *very, very, very, very bad*. unless you know exactly what you are doing. then it's only very, very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, please read the community guidelines, your question is poorly written hence the down votes and votes to close.

The code, which I hope you inherited and didn't write is missing a return statement at the end, i.e the path through the code that takes you to labels IL_EF or IL_124 do not return.

```
IL_EF:
this._self__55.movement.velocity = this._self__55.movement.velocity - this._self__55.movingPlatform.platformVelocity;

IL_124:
this.YieldDefault(1);

return someValue; // you need to return here
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a function that will return a boolean, but you have not defined a "return" statement after the "switch" statement. So if you set "return true;" or "return false;" after the last line, your function will work.